# angular cookies : jwt token injection

Tags: angular

I've got an API using JWT token for authentification. I'm using ngx cookie service and httpInterceptor to inject token for my requests. Everything is working fine except for images and videos. It's like the token is not injected as I've got a 403 error.

httpInterceptor :

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private authentService: AuthentService,
    private cookieService: CookieService
  ) {
    const token = this.authentService.getToken();
    const tok = 'Bearer ' + token;
    this.cookieService.set('Authorization', tok);
  }

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = this.authentService.getToken();

    if (!token) {
      return next.handle(req);
    }

    const req1 = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`),
    });

    return next.handle(req1);
  }
}
```

For my live stream video :

tv.component.ts

```
  tvHD() {
    this.screenHd = `/api/tv/${this.number}/stream/mjpg/hd`;
  }
```

tv.component.html

```
    <img src="{{ screenHd }}" class="screenSize" />
```

The cookie is injected as I can see it in my stockage.

Can you tell me what I'm missing here ? Frontend is angular and backend is java spring.

Comment: From the first line of Angular [`HttpInterceptor`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) docs: "_Intercepts and handles an [`HttpRequest`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest)_". So the interceptor only intercepts requests made through the Angular `HttpClient`. For other cases, like the `<img src=...>`, you'd have to do it manually. Or make a HTTP GET in the controller using the `HttpClient` and provide the response as the `src` in the template.

Comment: Hello Michael, thanks for the answer. The problem is that with the live stream I don't really have a response to inject in the src as the video never stops, the call is constant, that's why I've try my luck with cookies :/